# QuerySelector on ID with curly bracket in name

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating a dynamic filter and this is working fine but I've one problem. I'm selecting all filters on a querySelectorAll function combined with a php get function. Unfortunately some of the dynamic content has weird names like:

```
 (art) and more
```

With a split join function this will result in the following code:

```
document.querySelector('#(art)_and_more');
```

This will result into a error cause it's not a valid selection. Does anyone know a way how to solve this? 
I would like to keep my names as they are cause it's part of a big system.

Comment: Please post the php get function in the question too.

Comment: The php function wasn't relevant to this question, its more about the selector then the get function while this part is working perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an *ID*, then you'd use `getElementById` since by definition there can be only one match (IDs **must** be unique).

```
var element = document.getElementById("(art)_and_more");
```

In the general case, you'd use a quoted attribute selector:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("[id='(art)_and_more']");
// or
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[id="(art)_and_more"]');
```

...but again, IDs must be unique.

Comment: getElementById is working fine. I find it weird that this is accepted as a selector but in a querySelector it isn't. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DennisSpierenburg - `getElementById` doesn't take a selector, it takes an ID. So it's not weird at all. :-) `foo` is an ID. `#foo` is a selector for the ID `foo`. Selectors have a grammar and can be complex; IDs are just IDs.